# making three dimensional array that has an unknown amount of arrays inside

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to store data from a table, and I do not know how many lines will be in said table. My idea was to make a main array called data, a sub array for each line with just numeric labels (1,2,3,etc) and then inside each of those would be the actual data from each line, so it would be like this:

```
data
  ->1
    ->item1
    ->item2
    ->item3
  ->2
    ->item1
    ->item2
    ->item3
  ->3
    ->item1
    ->item2
    ->item3
```

ETC. I know how to work with multidimensional arrays and I know there are easy ways to accomplish this in java, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it in php.

Comment: Where exactly are you struggling? (maybe an example in java would help to understand your problem)

Comment: Have you already opened up a connection to the database? If yes, which library are you using (MySQL, MySQLi or PDO)? Also, do you know exactly what columns you want to get out?

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Comment: the data will be pulled from two tables in a database, and I'll be using MYSQLi

Comment: And what is the format of the data in the database? Do the rows that are returned correspond to table rows and the columns to columns?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly then yes that's true. Each row would be an entry in data (EX row 1 would be data[0], row 2 would be data[1], etc) and each column would be one of the items within that. so row 1 column 1 would be data[0]['item1']  and I misspoke earlier its a 2d array not a 3d array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep on adding to an array simply use the following code:

```
$myArray[] = 'another value';
```

Notice the `[]` this tells php to add another value to the array (without removing previous elements)

See here for a quick tutorial on mutidimensional arrays:

http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/multidimensional_arrays.php

And this:

http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/01/php-arrays-array-functions-and-multidimensional-arrays/

Comment: So if I had 3 items in $myArray already and I wanted a fourth I could do $myArray [] = 3; assuming it starts at 0, right?

Comment: yes, just keep in mind that 3 is the value (and not the position in the array) if you want to set a specific element you can do $myArray['element_neme'] or $myArray[2]

Comment: so could I just skip a step and do $myArray[0]['item1']="whatever"; even if $myArray[0] has yet to be created anywhere? would this just make an array inside $myArray and add "item1" to it with the value "whatever"?

Comment: yes :) php allows you to create things on the fly (it's one of the most useful and at the same time frustrating things about php)

Comment: Excellent then this looks to be exactly what I was looking for, thanks for all your information and help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Pretty sure `$myArray[0]['item1] = 'whatever';` gives an `E_NOTICE` atleast. You should do: `if(!isset($myArray[0])) { $myArray[0] = array(); }` first

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
foreach($rows as $v) {
  $data[] = array($v['item1'], $v['item2'], $v['item3']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To map mySQL data to a multidimensional array:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE uid = '1' ORDER BY id DESC");
$results = array();
$i = 0;
while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $results[$i] = $line;
    $i++;
}
```